# jquery will not wait for animate to finish before removing, why?

Tags: jquery

I was working on something simple, instead of just doing:

```
$(this).next().remove();
```

I wanted it to have a bit more flare, and wanted to add an animate function

```
$(this).next().slideUp().remove();
```

where it will slide up to hide the item before removing it.  While testing it with Chrome, it pretty much just removes the items and doesnt accomplish the smoothe transition i was expecting.

Testing without the remove has the items using slideUp() correctly.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with callback function of **[`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp)** method.

```
$(this).next().slideUp(function() {
  // remove the element after 
  // animation finished
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `slideUp` happens in the background.  To wait until it's done, use its callback.

```
$(this).next().slideUp(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The animation call is asynchronous in that it starts but the execution continues. The way to accomplish what you want is with a callback maybe like this:

```
 $(this).next().slideUp(function(){
     $(this).remove();
    });
```